# Infinite scroll with htmx in flask is not working for me

Tags: html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, htmx

This is my first time using htmx and I'm trying to use the infinite scroll but it's not working. This is my code below

```
@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET'])



def home():
    # pagination
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    all_data = Data.query.order_by(desc(Data.timestamp)).paginate(page = page, per_page = 20)

    if "hx_request"  in request.headers:
        return render_template("table.html",datas = all_data)
    return render_template("home.html", datas = all_data)
```

This is the html code i am trying to add the infinite scroll to

```
{% for data in datas.items %}
{% if loop.last and data.has_next %}
<tr hx-get="{{url_for('home', page = data.next_num)}}" hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="afterend">
{% else %}
    <tr>
  {% endif %} 
     
        <td scope="row">{{data.uuid}}</td>
        <td scope="row">{{data.timestamp}}</td>
        <td scope="row">{{data.decibel}}</td>
        
    </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is my home.html that contains the table

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>home</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<center>
<table class="table table-primary table-striped" >
    <tr> 
        <th scope="col">UUID</th>
        <th scope="col">Timestamp</th>
        <th scope="col">Decibel</th>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
    {% include 'table.html' %}


</tbody>


</table>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

I updated some things here and there but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows you a not very nice way of using htmx infinite scroll. It's pretty similar to your approach.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Record(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    items = [Record(name=f'Record-{i}') for i in range(100)]
    db.session.add_all(items)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    records = Record.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=20)
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

A macro is defined which uses the paginate object to add the htmx pattern for each last row of the loaded chunk as long as there is another page.

The [macro](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#macros) iterates over the elements of the loaded page, returning a table row for each entry. The attributes necessary for the infinite scroll pattern are added to the last row, provided there is another page.
In order to make the macro usable for other data records as well, the current object is sent back to the call within the iteration using `caller()`. This makes it usable as an argument in the nested block of the call.
See also the [`call`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#call) section in the documentation for a more detailed explanation.

```
{% macro htmx_infinite_table_rows(paginate, endpoint) -%}
  {% for item in paginate.items -%}
    {% if loop.last and paginate.has_next -%}
    <tr
      hx-get="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=paginate.next_num) }}"
      hx-trigger="revealed"
      hx-swap="afterend"
    >
    {% else -%}
    <tr>
    {% endif -%}
      {{ caller(item) }}
    </tr>
  {% endfor -%}
{% endmacro -%}

{% if 'hx_request' in request.headers -%}
  {% call(record) htmx_infinite_table_rows(records, 'index') -%}
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
  {% endcall -%}
{% else -%}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <style>
        .htmx-indicator {
          display:none;
        }
        .htmx-indicator.htmx-request {
          display:inline;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% call(record) htmx_infinite_table_rows(records, 'index') -%}
            <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
          {% endcall -%}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <center><img class="htmx-indicator" width="60" src="https://htmx.org/img/bars.svg"></center>
      
      <script 
        src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0" 
        integrity="sha384-EzBXYPt0/T6gxNp0nuPtLkmRpmDBbjg6WmCUZRLXBBwYYmwAUxzlSGej0ARHX0Bo" 
        crossorigin="anonymous" 
        defer></script>
    </body>
  </html>
{% endif -%}
```

---

###### Update:

You made a mistake when getting the attributes `has_next` and `next_num`. The code should be as follows.

```
{% for data in datas.items %}
  {% if loop.last and datas.has_next %}
  <tr hx-get="{{url_for('home', page=datas.next_num)}}" hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="afterend">
  {% else %}
  <tr>
  {% endif %}
    <td scope="row">{{data.uuid}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{data.timestamp}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{data.decibel}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please could you shed more light on the macros

Comment: @AlabiOluwabusayoJoseph I've tried to expand my answer accordingly. The macro is only used to avoid writing a selected block of code more than once. Feel free to ask if you need further explanations.

Comment: Please I'm new to stuffs like this so my questions can be a little bit funny. So what does the endpoint do and what value is to be passed into the endpoint

Comment: The endpoint is the identifier/name of the function that will be called to load the data. [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) hereby generates the URL from the route and the passed arguments, which are appended as parameters.

Comment: The generated URL is `/?page=<page-number>`. Where page-number is the number of the next page.

Comment: After taking some time to understand and also try the code you wrote up here, I have come across another problem. The infinite scroll is not working.It's only doing the pagination aspect the htmx isn't working. Please could you help me

Comment: I've added a loading indicator, but I don't understand your issue at this time. What exactly do you mean by "htmx isn't working"?

Comment: I'm getting only the first 20 pages. No infinite scroll, just the first 20, I edited my code based on what i understood from yours but it's still not working. Please could you help me check it out I'll edit it up in the post now

Comment: I took the trouble to test your suggestion and expanded my answer again. I assume that I was able to help you and that you accept my answer by ticking the appropriate box.